# If $Ker(T^2)=Ker(T)$ show that $V=Ker(T)\oplus Im(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having troubles with this problem

> Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Show that: $$Ker(T^2)=Ker(T)\Rightarrow V=Ker(T)\oplus Im(T)$$

So far, using the rank-nullity theorem (and the fact that $Im(T^2)\subseteq Im(T)$) I've showed that $Im(T^2)= Im(T)$. Then, I want to show that $V=Ker(T)+Im(T)$, so I write any $v \in V$ as $v=T(v)+(v-T(v))$, with the first term obviously in $Im(T)$. To conclude this part, I'd like to show that $v-T(v) \in Ker(T)$, I'm inclined to think that $T^2\equiv T$, but I'm not sure if I have enough information to conclude that.

Comment: You don't have enough information to conclude $T = T^2$.  Consider rotating the plane through $\pi/2$ radians...

Comment: You are assuming that $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Yes, I forgot to add that (I used the rank-nullity theorem, so I used the fact that $V$ is finite-dimensional). Anyway, I solved the problem thanks to Omnomnomnom hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** By the rank-nullity theorem, you know that the image and kernel have dimensions that add to $n$. What you need to show (using the given information) is that
$$
Ker(T) \cap Im(T)=\{0\}
$$

Comment: It may be helpful for you to know that the converse to this implication is also true.

Comment: Yeah, I already proved the converse. And thanks for the hint, I did this (correct me if I'm wrong please). After proving that $Ker(T)\cap Im(T)=\{0\}$, we have that $dim(Ker(T)+Im(T))=dim(Ker(T))+dim(Im(T))=n$. So, as is obvious that $Ker(T)+Im(T)\subseteq V$, we conclude that $Ker(T)+Im(T)=V$, and as $Ker(T)\cap Im(T)=\{0\}$, then $Ker(T)+Im(T)\oplus V$

Comment: Yep, that all seems in order (except for your typo at the end)